# Excel - Application.GetSaveAsFilename Prompting on Read Only Files

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I've just upgraded to Excel 2010 from 2003. An internal add-in that is heavily used uses the Application.GetSaveAsFilename method to prompt for file names to be used for an export process (exporting information from the current Excel file into an xml configuration file).

In 2003, even if they selected a Read Only file, I didn't get any prompts (which is what I want) leaving it up to me to handle read-only issues (which I do...e.g. I check the file out of source control). However, after upgrading to 2010, I can't select a filename if that file exists and is readonly, forcing me to manually go checkout files first (which is a major downer in terms of proficiency when I'm exporting ~60 files per day).

Does anyone know of any settings/workarounds so that Excel 2010 doesn't prevent (or even prompt hopefully) selecting a filename of a previously existing/readonly file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Does it help if you use Application.GetOpenFilename instead?

```
Sub PromptForFilename()
    ret = Application.GetOpenFilename
    MsgBox ret
End Sub
```

This doesn't give me any errors for a read-only file.

Comment: This only allows you to select existing files.  There are times when I need to save a new file.